# How to separate php from html and seperate php again?

Tags: php, html

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["orderNumber"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["orderDate"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["requiredDate"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
    <td><a  title="Click To Edit Order Detail" rel="facebox" href="editorderdetail.php?id=' .$row["orderNumber"];.'"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit </button></a> 
      <a href="#" id="'.$row["orderNumber"];. '" class="delete" title="Click To Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button></a></td>
   </tr>

  ';
 }
```

I expect to get the $row["orderNumber"] in the url for edit and delete purpose.

Comment: You got a typo near `$row["orderNumber"];` - in the first and second link, take away that semicolon.

Comment: Enable error reporting and you should be getting errors.

Comment: It doesn't work after I remove that semicolon. When I click on the edit button is show this URL : http://localhost/cwp3034/Assignment/admin/editorderdetail.php?id=%3C?php%20echo%20$row[

Comment: The code you have posted in this question does not represent that value, unless `$row["orderNumber"]` contains `<?php echo` inside it.

Comment: i have added <?php echo that's why it shows the URL :http://localhost/cwp3034/Assignment/admin/editorderdetail.php?id=%3C?php%20echo%20$row[

Comment: But that string you have is already in PHP.. You just need to concatenate it as you are doing in the question, except you have to remove the `;` at the end of each `$row["orderNumber"]`

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem. Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using an editor with syntax highlighting, so the obvious errors are easily fixed. Try following:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= '<tr><td>' .
    $row["orderNumber"] . '</td><td>' .
    $row["orderDate"] . '</td><td>' .
    $row["requiredDate"] . '</td><td>' .
    $row["status"] . '</td><td>' .
    '<a  title="Click To Edit Order Detail" rel="facebox" href="editorderdetail.php?id=' . $row["orderNumber"] . '">' .
    '<button class="btn btn-warning btn-mini"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit </button></a>' .
    '<a href="#" id="' . $row["orderNumber"] . 'class="delete" title="Click To Delete">' .
    '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button></a>' .
    '</td></tr>';
}
```